# ClassCastException -- Error on Redhat, not on Windows

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, redhat

I have my website running on Tomcat. When I try to access one of my pages to do a status check, it checks on a particular JAR file. On Red Hat 5, but not on Windows, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: LoggingPasshashInfo cannot be cast to PasshashInfo
```

I got this JAR from a third party and am using it just as I got it. According to Apache's tatus page, the RH setup is on Tomcat version 7.0.22 and JVM version 1.6.0_27-b07. Windows is on Tomcat 7.0.19 and JVM 1.6.0_26-b03. Red Hat's Tomcat was upgraded from 6.0.33 over the course of trying to get this fixed.

Anyway, I'm a bit new at this and, aside from getting the setups to look as similar as possible, I'm not sure how to go about solving this. Any help would be fine, and if I've failed to share any important details, let me know. And just to reiterate, the JAR I'm working with is a black box.

Full error:

```
Java.lang.ClassCastException: com.adobe.adept.fulfillment.test.LoggingPasshashInfo cannot be cast to com.adobe.adept.fulfillment.PasshashInfo
    at com.adobe.adept.fulfillment.servlet.Fulfill.<clinit>(Fulfill.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:836)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: I'm guessing that the JAR file that contains one or the other of those two classes is different on the two systems.  Or you may have two JAR files containing the same class, and essentially have them in opposite order in your class path.

Comment: Following Daniel's lead: 1) Is this library multi-platform? 2) If not, are you making sure you're only packaging the OS-specific jar?

Comment: I originally downloaded the single JAR on Windows and got it working there first. Then I transferred it to RH over the local network. That wouldn't mess with the contents of the JAR, would it? And both of those classes should be in that one JAR, though com.adobe.adept.fulfillment.servlet.Fulfill is not.

Comment: Paolo, I just saw your comment. That is definitely something I'll have to look into since... well, I sort of assumed it would work since the other JARs I'm using seem to have no issue between Unix and Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have more than one copy of the jar file installed on the Linux server. The result of this could be that the same jar is loaded by multiple classloaders. Classes that would normally be related, but are loaded by unrelated classloaders, are not convertible via a cast. Check carefully for other copies of the jar file -- for example, in Tomcat's top-level "server/lib" directory -- and remove all but one.